# Can't call method "add_worksheet" on an undefined value?

Tags: excel, perl, cgi, perl-module, cgi-bin

here is my cgi code , perl.xls file is present in the save folder as the script.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
 use CGI;
 use DBI;
 use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
 my $cgi = CGI->new;
 my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');
 my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
 $worksheet->write(0,0,'value');
```

And when i run the script i get this error

```
Software error:

Can't call method "add_worksheet" on an undefined value at /var/www/cgi-bin/excel.cgi line 17.

 For help, please send mail to the webmaster (root@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

Comment: Check return value of `new()`. `my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls') or die "can't open?";`

Comment: @Сухой27  its returning cant open ..

Comment: @sp1rs find out why? `...or die can't open: $!;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You're calling a method (`add_worksheet()`) on an undefined value. You're calling that method on `$workbook`, so you need to investigate how that value is set. It comes from this line:

```
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('perl.xls');
```

So it's probably worth looking at the documentation for the `new()` method in [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel). It says this:

> If the file cannot be created, due to file permissions or some other
>   reason, `new` will return `undef`. Therefore, it is good practice to 
>   check the return value of `new` before proceeding. As usual the Perl 
>   variable `$!` will be set if there is a file creation error. You will 
>   also see one of the warning messages detailed in "[DIAGNOSTICS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#DIAGNOSTICS)":
>
> ```
> my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('protected.xls');
> die "Problems creating new Excel file: $!" unless defined $workbook;
> ```

I'd guess that your CGI program is trying to write a file in a directory where doesn't have the required permissions. You might want give `new()` the full path to a directory where the file should be created.

It's also worth pointing out this warning from the documentation:

> **Note: This module is in maintenance only mode** and in future will 
>   only be updated with bug fixes. The newer, more feature rich and API
>   compatible [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) module is recommended instead. See,
>   "[Migrating to Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel#Migrating-to-Excel::Writer::XLSX)".

Comment: it will work only if u create a .xls file before with changed permission , then it worked for me. Thx davecross.

Comment: That's not true. It will work as long as your user has permissions to create a file in the target directory.